# Launch app from URL containing question mark

Tags: android, url, android-intent, android-activity

I know how to deal with URLs such as: http://example.com/xyz. However, my URL contains question mark as follows: https://example.com/?xyz

So when I do the `getIntent().getData().getPath()` I get the output as `/`. The question marking is somehow limiting the processing. How do I deal with it?

Here is the `intent-filter` in my `manifest`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Here is the code from my `Activity`:

```
if (getIntent() != null && data != null && data.getPathSegments().size() >= 1) {
    Log.d("tagit", getIntent().getData().getPath().toString());
}
```

Now, the log shows blank.

Comment: Are you passing the information in bundle?

Comment: No bundle. The link is shared via 3rd party apps such as Whatsapp, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got it working by getting the complete link using the following:

```
data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
```

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25295636/3739412

Comment: mark your answer as correct so that it could help others

Comment: I says I can accept it after 2 days, so I'll do it then :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to **encode the URL** to handle the question marks/white space/special characters. I am sharing a simple code snippet. It may help you.

```
String urlStr = "http://example.com/?xyz";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

And another more simpler solution can be:

```
private static final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(path, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
```

Comment: What do those parameters in URI() do? Also, I want the urlStr String to remain as such when sent to a user via an application such as SMS. Otherwise, it the user doesn't have my app installed, he/she won't be able to open the link via a browser.

Comment: I shared all of them as a generic solution. You may not need all those parameters.

Comment: urlEncoded is still the same as path ("http://example.com/?xyz"). So my problem is not yet solved.