# create html link that open an android application

Tags: android, html

I want to create an simple html href link on my mobile website that will open an android application like waze, whatsapp or viber. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm no expert in Android, but iOS, for example, uses custom url schemes for this purpose. For example, `pythonista://something` would open an app called Pythonista.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289586/open-android-app-from-url-using-intent-filter-not-working

Comment: <a href="intent:#Intent;action=my_action;end">Link to my stuff</a> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773958/open-android-application-from-a-web-page

Answer (score 0):

For start Vkontakte application and open profile page I used:

```
if (isVKAppInstalled(context)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format("vkontakte://profile/%d", vkUserId)));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And method for check if app installed:

```
public static boolean isVKAppInstalled(Context context) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        boolean isInstalled;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(VK_PACKAGE_URI, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            isInstalled = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            isInstalled = false;
        }
        return isInstalled;
    }
```