# Open app when user visits url

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

My problem is that I set my manifest but visiting the website still just loads it in chrome and doesn't open the app. Here's my manifest code for the main activity:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: can you share the url of the website? are you testing it with www.example.com?

Comment: Testing with www.example.com

Comment: Some ideas are found here in [Open Android app from URL using intent-filter not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289586/open-android-app-from-url-using-intent-filter-not-working).

Comment: the intent-filter is for when you tap on a link to certain url not for when you write the url on your browser

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense. Thanks